# Auto-executable .exe within iframe

Tags: javascript, java, html, iframe, autorun

I am trying to run Setup.exe automatically within an iframe.

Once the site visitor into the customer panel after registration bring up a window of java to run the setup.exe

This software will be executed will be a remote access program for my clients who are asking helpdesk.

So I'm trying to make a shape with the client to run my executable directly from the page without the need to download.

See an example of how I'm doing:

**main.js**

```
var btnTitleChange = $.button("Let\'s change Frame title")
    .on_click(changeTitle,"Wow, I changed!");

var frame = $.frame("Demo Application")
    .layout($.layout("table",[[20,-1,20],[20,40,10,-1,20]]))
    .add($.button("About").on_click(alert),"1,1")
    .add(btnTitleChange,"1,3");

frame.show();

function changeTitle(title){frame.title(title);}

function alert(){
    js.alert("Welcome to JavaScript executable!"); };
```

**includes/java.js**

```
importPackage(Packages.java.lang)
importPackage(Packages.java.awt)
importPackage(Packages.java.awt.event)
importPackage(Packages.javax.swing)
importPackage(Packages.info.clearthought.layout);

//============================= START OF CLASS ==============================//
//CLASS: java_object                                                         //
//===========================================================================//
 /**
  * A reference to the Java Object class
  * @class
  */
java_object = function(inst){
    /**
     * Data container for this object
     * @private
     */
    this._d = {}
    /**
     * Contains the actual Java instance for this object
     * To access it use the <b>instance()</b> method
     * @private
     */
    this._inst = new java.lang.Object();    
    this.instance = function(){return this._inst;}
    this.equals = function(o){return (undefined===o._inst)?false:this._inst.equals(o.instance());}
    this.getClass = function(){return this.instance().getClass();}
    this.hashCode = function(){return this.instance().hashCode();}
    this.toString = function(){return this.instance().toString();}
};
//===========================================================================//
//CLASS: java_object                                                         //
//============================== END OF CLASS ===============================//

//============================= START OF CLASS ==============================//
//CLASS: java_component                                                      //
//===========================================================================//
 /**
  * A reference to the Java Component class
  * @augments java_object
  * @class
  */
java_component = function(){
    this._inst = null;
    //========================= START OF METHOD ===========================//
    //  METHOD: on_click                                                   //
    //=====================================================================//
       /**
        * Sets a function to be executed, when the mouse is clicked over this
        * widget
        * @param title the title to be shown in the frame
        * @type mixed
        */
    this.on_click=function(fn,arg1,arg2,arg3){
        var adapter  = new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {  mousePressed: function(e){fn(arg1,arg2,arg3);} };        
        this.instance().addMouseListener(adapter);
        return this;
    };
    //=====================================================================//
    //  METHOD: on_click                                                   //
    //========================== END OF METHOD ============================//
};
java_component.prototype = new java_object();
java_component.constructor == java_object;
//===========================================================================//
//CLASS: java_component                                                      //
//============================== END OF CLASS ===============================//

//============================= START OF CLASS ==============================//
//CLASS: java_container                                                         //
//===========================================================================//
 /**
  * A reference to the Java Container class
  * @augments java_component
  * @class
  */
java_container = function(){
    this._inst = new java.awt.Container();  
    //========================= START OF METHOD ===========================//
  //  METHOD: add                                                        //
  //=====================================================================//
       /**
        * Adds an object to the container.
        * @type void
        */
    this.add=function(object,constraints){
        if(undefined==constraints){
            (undefined===object.instance)?this.instance().add(object):this.instance().add(object.instance());
        }else{
            if(constraints.toUpperCase()=="NORTH"){
                (undefined===object.instance)?this.instance().add(object,BorderLayout.NORTH):this.instance().add(object.instance(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
            }else if(constraints.toUpperCase()=="SOUTH"){
                (undefined===object.instance)?this.instance().add(object,BorderLayout.SOUTH):this.instance().add(object.instance(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            }else if(constraints.toUpperCase()=="EAST"){
                (undefined===object.instance)?this.instance().add(object,BorderLayout.EAST):this.instance().add(object.instance(),BorderLayout.EAST);
            }else if(constraints.toUpperCase()=="WEST"){
                (undefined===object.instance)?this.instance().add(object,BorderLayout.WEST):this.instance().add(object.instance(),BorderLayout.WEST);
            }else{
                (undefined===object.instance)?this.instance().add(object,constraints):this.instance().add(object.instance(),constraints);
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
  //=====================================================================//
  //  METHOD: add                                                        //
  //========================== END OF METHOD ============================//

  //========================= START OF METHOD ===========================//
  //  METHOD: layout                                                     //
  //=====================================================================//
       /**
        * Sets the layout for this container.
        * @type void
        */
    this.layout = function(layout){
        (undefined===layout.instance)?this.instance().setLayout(layout):this.instance().setLayout(layout.instance());
        return this;
    };
    //=====================================================================//
  //  METHOD: layout                                                     //
  //========================== END OF METHOD ============================//

    return this;
}
java_container.prototype = new java_component();
java_container.constructor == java_component;
//===========================================================================//
//CLASS: j_container                                                         //
//============================== END OF CLASS ===============================//

//============================= START OF CLASS ==============================//
//CLASS: java_frame                                                          //
//===========================================================================//
 /**
  * A reference to the Java Window class
  * @class
  */
java_frame = function(title){
    this._inst = (undefined===title)?new javax.swing.JFrame(""):new javax.swing.JFrame(title);  
    this._inst.setSize(600,400);    
    this._inst.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    //========================= START OF METHOD ===========================//
  //  METHOD: show                                                       //
  //=====================================================================//
    this.show=function(){this._inst.setVisible(true);};
    //=====================================================================//
  //  METHOD: show                                                       //
  //========================== END OF METHOD ============================//

    //========================= START OF METHOD ===========================//
  //  METHOD: close                                                      //
  //=====================================================================//
    this.close=function(){this._inst.setVisible(false);};
    //=====================================================================//
  //  METHOD: close                                                      //
  //========================== END OF METHOD ============================//

    //========================= START OF METHOD ===========================//
  //  METHOD: on_close                                                   //
  //=====================================================================//
       /**
        * Sets or retrieves the title of this frame.
        * @param title the title to be shown in the frame
        * @type mixed
        */
    this.on_close=function(fn,arg1,arg2,arg3){
        var adapter  = new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() { windowClosing: function(e){fn(arg1,arg2,arg3);} };
        this.instance().addWindowListener(adapter);
        return this;
    };
    //=====================================================================//
  //  METHOD: on_close                                                   //
  //========================== END OF METHOD ============================//

  //========================= START OF METHOD ===========================//
  //  METHOD: title                                                      //
  //=====================================================================//
       /**
        * Sets or retrieves the title of this frame.
        * @param title the title to be shown in the frame
        * @type mixed
        */
    this.title=function(/**String*/title){
        if(undefined===title)return this.instance().getTitle();
        else{this.instance().setTitle(title);}
        return this;
    };
    //=====================================================================//
  //  METHOD: title                                                      //
  //========================== END OF METHOD ============================//
    return this;
}
java_frame.prototype = new java_container();
java_frame.constructor == java_container;
//===========================================================================//
//CLASS: j_frame                                                             //
//============================== END OF CLASS ===============================//

//============================= START OF CLASS ==============================//
//CLASS: j_layout                                                            //
//===========================================================================//
/**
* A reference to the Java Container class
* @augments j_object
* @class
*/
java_layout = function(type,constraints){
    if(type==="border")this._inst = new java.awt.BorderLayout();
    if(type==="flow")this._inst = new java.awt.FlowLayout();
    if(type==="table"){
        this._inst = new TableLayout(constraints);
    }   
    return this;
}
java_layout.prototype = new java_object();
//===========================================================================//
//CLASS: j.layout                                                            //
//============================== END OF CLASS ===============================//

//============================= START OF CLASS ==============================//
//CLASS: j_button                                                            //
//===========================================================================//
 /**
  * A reference to the Java JButton class
  * <div style="position: relative; top: 10px; left: 10px; font-size: 11px; font-family: verdana; color:crimson;">&nbsp;Example&nbsp;</div>
  * <div style="border: 1px dashed silver; margin: 10px; padding: 5px; background: cornsilk; font-family: monospace; font-size: 12px;">
  * var button = new j_button();<br>
  *     button.text("Click me");<br>
  *     button.on_click(js.alert,"I was clicked");
  * </div>
  * @augments j_component
  * @class    
  */
java_button = function(text){
    this._inst = (undefined===text)?new javax.swing.JButton(""):new javax.swing.JButton(text);
    //========================= START OF METHOD ===========================//
  //  METHOD: text                                                       //
  //=====================================================================//
    this.text=function(text){
        if(undefined===text){return this.instance().getText();}
        this.instance().setText(text);
    };
    //=====================================================================//
  //  METHOD: text                                                       //
  //========================== END OF METHOD ============================//
    return this;
}
java_button.prototype = new java_component();
//===========================================================================//
//CLASS: java_button                                                         //
//============================== END OF CLASS ===============================//

//============================= START OF CLASS ==============================//
//CLASS: namespace                                                           //
//===========================================================================//
/** @namespace */
$ = {
    _button:java_button,
    _frame:java_frame,
    _layout:java_layout,
    _object:java_object,
    button:function(name){
        return new this._button(name);
    },
    frame:function(title){
        return new this._frame(title);
    },
    layout:function(name,constraints){
        return new this._layout(name,constraints);
    },
    object:function(){
        return new this._object();
    }
};
//===========================================================================//
//CLASS: namespace                                                           //
//============================== END OF CLASS ===============================//
```

**includes/js.js**

```
/** @namespace */
js = {
    _loaded:[], // Reference to all the loaded script files
    alert:function(msg){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><font size=\"3\" color=\"red\">"+msg+"</font></html>", "Alert",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    },
    echo:function(msg){System.out.print(msg);},
    getcwd:function(){
        return System.getProperty("user.dir");
    },
    include:function(path){
        var id = path.split("\\").join("_").split(" ").join("___");
        if(undefined === this._loaded[id]){this._loaded[id]=id;}
        load(path.split("\\").join("/"));
    },
    include_once:function(path){
        var id = path.split("\\").join("_").split(" ").join("___");
        if(undefined === this._loaded[id]){
            this._loaded[id]=id; load(path.split("\\").join("/"));
        }
    },
    version:1.2
}
js.include("includes/java.js");
```

**I would like to stay as shown in the image link:**

[image]

If anyone can send me a ready with Iframe ready so I can study more about it and be able to practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Applets to show your java application.

But modern browsers (like Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox soon) ends the support to plugins NPAPI, like Adobe Flash and Java Plugin.

So Java Applets are obsolete and very unsecure too.

But if you want to do so, Oracle recommended to use IE or Safari.

See official page: https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.
Sera has another solution to something I can manage to do that?

Comment: I don't know your reasons, but for me it is impracticable.

Comment: I'm riding a Help Desk site
And we create a remote access system.
customer area requires that you download and install the .msi file
many low and customers do not know run.
So often I have to go in the customer's house to perform
it ends up giving me a lot of work.
So I'm trying to do that
to facilitate, I do not want to do anything illegal.
So I can see if I can find a solution for me not be going to the customer. Many of them live far away and few understand it and can not find the file to run.
But I understand your concern in a matter of ethical terms.
But just want the same ease. for me

Comment: It is not illegal, but it is not OK, try another approach, using a specific remote tool, like VNC, Team Viewer, AnyDesk or something like that.